# JPA/Hibernate OneToMany relationship from Embedded entity by non-PK columns

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

JPA Model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "BASE_RECORD")
public class BaseRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DB_ID")
    public Long id;

    @Embedded
    public DeclarantRecord declarant;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DeclarantRecord {

    @Column(name = "DECLARANT_ID")
    public String declarantId;

    @Column(name = "DECLARANT_IDE")
    public String identificationNumber;

    @Column(name = "DECLARANT_NAME")
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "baseRecord", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<DeclarantAddress> addresses;
}
```

---

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "ADDRESS_RECORD")
public class DeclarantAddress {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DB_ID")
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERS_ID", referencedColumnName = "DECLARANT_ID")
    public BaseRecord baseRecord;
}
```

When fetching a `BaseRecord` from DB by using a Spring Boot `JPARepository`, I receive the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(DECLARANT_ID) of DeclarantAddress.baseRecord referencing BaseRecord not mapped to a single property
```

I cannot understand what's wrong and moreover, if I inline the `DeclarantRecord` in the `BaseRecord` entity by declaring all the properties in there and moving the exact same relationship declaration in the `BaseRecord` class, everything works perfectly.

Comment: `referencedColumnName = "DECLARANT_ID"` is optional. What happens if you leave it out?

Comment: It works, but it uses the @Id attribute for joining, not the DECLARANT_ID column, which is what I want.

Comment: @Dina Bogdan, PERS_ID is not mapped to DECLARANT_ID, so remove PERS_ID and see if that works.

Comment: from where to remove that one? PERS_ID is the business key used for joining the two tables.

Comment: `PERS_ID` should stay, that part is correct. Generally I don't quite see why this kind of setup. If you want a base class, `@MappedSuperclass` would probably be easier. As to why you get the error: hibernate checks if the target class has a field that is either matching the name or has an `@Column` with that column name. However, this you have defined in the nested class. If you reference a `DeclarantRecord` directly, it would probably work directly

Comment: The base class is not an abstract class, it's just a name, please don't think of it as a class that should be derived. Moreover, referencing a `DeclarantRecord` directly won't work, too. I already tried that case and I receive this kind of exception:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on DeclarantAddress.declarant references an unknown entity: DeclarantRecord`

I suspect that this exception is being thrown because the `DeclarantAddress` is not an entity.

Comment: @Dina Bogdan, I meant to say that if you want to join by DECLARANT_ID, then leave only referencedColumnName="DECLARANT_ID" in JoinColumn. The name attribute in JoinColumn is also optional, so you need either name or referencedColumnName.

Comment: @dsp_user one table contains `DECLARANT_ID` while the other contains `PERS_ID` so both of them should be specified, because effectively the join will take place by `DeclarantRecord.DECLARANT_ID = DeclarantAddress.PERS_ID`. And please notice that `PERS_ID` is not the PK of the `DeclarantAddress`.

Comment: @Dina Bogdan, I see, I'm guessing Hibernate then expects to see something like DeclaredAddress.PERS_ID = BaseRecord.some_id , rather than BaseRecord.DeclarantRecord.DECLARANT_ID.

Comment: @Dina Bogdan, how about adding a declarantId field in the BaseRecords class? I understand that this seems redundant given declarent property but this may help resolve the error.

Comment: It might be related to [HHH-12930](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12930). Which hibernate version are you using? It is supposedly fixed with  version 6.1.5

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me:

Move
`@Column(name = "DECLARANT_ID") public String declarantId;` to `BaseRecord` class.

The rest can stay the same.